# Select with multiple columns in AngularJS not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

[**Demo link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/P04VsCjSFOI6BsrcCbTE?p=preview)

Hi all,

I created a sample for select with multiple columns in AngularJS. which is working fine if I pass the value directly like this:

```
$scope.rowDatas = [
                     { ID: "09-14-002880", PatientName: "PRAVEEN KUMAR", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: 9879878971, patientId: "test" },
                     { ID: "09-13-000188", PatientName: "VAR", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "ZXC12" },
                     { ID: "09-05-019825", PatientName: "KARMA", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "ZA2545635" },
                     { ID: "09-04-010524", PatientName: "FRANKLIN ANTHONY", Gender: "Male", Age: "20", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z7552396" },
                     { ID: "09-08-009303", PatientName: "DARYOUSH", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z2548467" },
                     { ID: "09-12-031048", PatientName: "SMITA", Gender: "Female", Age: "20", mobileNumber: 9880222187, patientId: "Z2296538" },
                     { ID: "09-11-026001", PatientName: "ADITYA DILIP", Gender: "Male", Age: "29", mobileNumber: '', patientId: "Z2277913" }
    ];
```

But what I exactly need is I need to get the value from factory

```
dtfactory.getdata().then(function(response){
  //$scope.rowDatas = response.data;
})
```

Here `response.data` also contain same data.If I comment direct code and uncomment factory code its not working may I know where I did mistake? can any one help me this.

Comment: Make sure your factory function `dtfactory.getdata()` should return promise. Or you may share your factory code too.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this in your controller

```
$scope.rowDatas = dtfactory.getdata().then(function(response){
  $scope.rowDatas = response.data;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

first get the json data and call the displayTable function:

```
   dtfactory.getdata().then(function(response){
      $scope.rowDatas = response.data;
      dispalyTable();
    })

    function dispalyTable(){
      $scope.gridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: $scope.gridheaders,
                    rowData: $scope.rowDatas,
                };

         //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid_'+textBoxId);
            new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, $scope.gridOptions);
         //}); 
    }
```

Comment: @ Harry thanks for reply, i changed your code, but not working

Comment: could you please tell me what is not working..? Is $scope.rowDatas is not updating?